Save model with saveRDS but the rds file is too large to open
I saved my models in R using the saveRDS() function, which usually took half a day and it is a large file. When I tried to load the rds back to R, it gave an error: cannot allocate vector of size 8.0 gb. My computer has 64 G RAM.
Is there a way to fix this?
Thank you.

Does this help? R memory management / cannot allocate vector of size n Mb

I know that models can grow large pretty quickly. I'm still curious about the size of your model/data, i.e. are you dealing with big data (hundreds of columns, millions of rows)? If not, I'm wondering if the model is maybe "overspecified".

@deschen My models include 17 csv files, each only contain dozens of rows and columns. The files themselves are not large, but I am using the multi species occupancy model with 15 species included. Therefore the resulting model object is fairly large.
